# Heat map on chromosome with specific input format

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I try to plot values per scaffolds and per species with an heat map.
I have consulted the following post to set up my script:
[How to plot a heat map by chromosome in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55893099/how-to-plot-a-heat-map-by-chromosome-in-r)

But the input table itself is unusual, and follow this format:

```
structure(list(scaffolds = c("Scaffolds_0", "Scaffolds_1", "Scaffolds_2", 
"Scaffolds_3", "Scaffolds_4", "Scaffolds_5", "Scaffolds_6", "Scaffolds_7", 
"Scaffolds_8"), Specie_1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
0L), Specie_2 = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L), Specie_3 = c(0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L), Specie_4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L), Specie_5 = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

I wish to output one column per species and compare the scaffolds value using different colors as figured in the picture below:

[image: Heat map output]

Would anyone know if `plot_ly` in ggplot2 could produce such a plot?

Comment: To give you any advice on your script you should include your script in your post. From your data I would suggest to have a look on how to convert from wide to long in order to convert the five cols into a tidy format.

Comment: Thanks stefan, I didn't know what were long data, it was informative.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figured out how to plot this data set.

The packages I used:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
```

The table has been converted from wide to long using the melt() function:

```
melt_table <- melt(table)
```

Columns had to be re-named:

```
colnames(melt_table) <- c("Scaffolds", "Species", "Values")
```

And the heat map has been plotted with `ggplot2::geom_tile`:

```
ggplot(melt_table, aes(Species , Scaffolds)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = Values), colour = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Drosera_capensis. Good job. +1. Always the best way to learn is to figure out a solution yourself. I made an edit to include the packages and the output so that your answer is even more helpful for others. Best S.